# Using a comma before which

Tags: grammar, commas

So is it really wrong to put a , before "which"?

e.g.

The nameofthegame is the second HTML5 game we created for the campaign, which focuses on interactive marketing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a comma or not depends on whether the phrase after the comma is *restrictive* or *nonrestrictive*. A nonrestrictive phrase adds a little bit of additional information but in contrast to a restrictive phrase it can be left out without changing the meaning.

Thus in your case I would suggest the comma to be correct, since the latter part only adds further information and the first part becomes not wrong after leaving the second part.